# Mathematica 11.1 kernel not running

Tags: windows, version-11.1

I was using *Mathematica* 11.1 under Windows 10, 64 bit. Yesterday morning I had a Windows 10 update and during the morning my virus scanner AVG warned me that one of the Windows files was corrupted with the virus `Win32/Herz.b`. Very likely a false alarm, but I did not take any risk and allowed AVG to protect me.

Yesterday and today I did quite a lot with the Workbench and *Mathematica* 11.0.  I do not remember if I have used *Mathematica* 11.1 as well, but anyway, since this afternoon in Mathematica 11.1 the frontend works nicely, but the kernel fails.

For example, when I try to evaluate `1+1`, in the upper left corner I see *Mathematica* running, the cell bracket is dark, and then everything stops: the message that it is running disappears, the cell bracket becomes normal, but no `In`- and `Out`-labels and no output.

When I use `LinkSnooper` and evaluate `1+1`, `LinkSnooper` starts up as usual, but almost immediately a window pops up showing "Wolfram Kernel for Windows does not work any more."

Of course I am not sure that this behaviour has something to do with the AVG protection. But anyway, following the advice on the AVG website I used the RemovalTool for completely removing AVG, reinstalled AVG and moreover reinstalled *Mathematica* 11.1. That did not help, the symptoms still are the same.

Fortunately, the problem is restricted to *Mathematica* 11.1. I can use *Mathematica* 10.4 and 11.0 normally.

Have other people had similar experiences? What can I do more than reinstalling *Mathematica*? All help to get *Mathematica* 11.1 running again is highly appreciated.

**Update**

As I wrote, I was doing quite a lot with the Workbench and *Mathematica* 11.0. I just found that one of my attempts seems to have lead to an automatic loading of a context. At the moment I have no idea how I can get rid of this autoloading. I had a look at the `Global Options`, found one place where that context turned up and removed it. I forgot what option it was. It did not help, when I restart *Mathematica*, the context is still loaded. But to my surprise, now the *Mathematica* 11.1 kernel runs again! Nice that it works again, but nevertheless unsatisfactory, because of both the reason and the solution for the loss of a kernel seem have to do with the Workbench.

**Update 2**

The application that I was playing with has in the `PacletInfo.m` file explicitely version *Mathematica* 11.0. What might have happened is that when *Mathematica* 11.1 started up, due to an incorrect `Global Option` setting it despite the restriction loaded the application and thereby tried to use some `LibraryFunction`s that silently crash the kernel, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140758/20253).

Comment: Can you run just the Kernel?

Comment: Maybe the affected Windows system file is corrupted? I'd suggest running `sfc /scannow`. If it was my PC I'd do a malware scan from a bootable antivirus too, just to be sure.

Comment: @Rolf. No, that gives the same behaviour as LinkSnooper. The window shows Mathematica 11.1.0 Kernel etc, Copyright etc. and then another window pops up saying that Wolfram Kernel for Windows does not work any more. If it has to do with a corrupted windows file, that must be a file used only by Mathematica 11.1, since 11.0 and 10.4 operate normally.

Comment: @Simon. Never heard of `sfc/scannow`, glad to know that it exists, thanks for  mentioning it. But unfortunately, it did not report any problem.

Comment: But you do not get an error code, like mentioned here: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/917946 ?

Comment: Hi @Rolf. No, nothing at all. The kernel silently crashes and the screen indicating that the kernel is not running any more comes from windows, I think.

Comment: @Rolf. Please see the update. I am not amused.

Comment: I also had a bit of problems in Workbench when switching between 11.0 and 11.1, but all can be solved.If Wolfram support cannot help you by next week, let's skype.